# Traverse Tree in Nodejs with Promises

Tags: node.js, tree, promise

Given a simple user tree:

```
users:

id | name  | parent_id
1  | Bob   | NULL
2  | Jan   | 1
3  | Mat   | 2
4  | Irene | 2
5  | Ellie | 2
6  | Laura | 5
7  | Uma   | 6
```

I am trying to walk it with this code:

```
addChildren: function(db, treeUsers, parentId) {
  const main = this;
  var sql = Sql.select().from('users')
    .where('parent_id = ?', parentId)
    .toParam();

  return db.execute(sql.text, sql.values)
    .then(function([rs,meta]) {
      rs.map(function(obj) { 
          treeUsers[obj.id] = obj;
      });

      return treeUsers;
  });
},

getTreeUsers: function(db, depth) {
  const main = this;
  const rootNodeId = 1;

  var treeUsers = {};
  const getChildren = function(parentId) {
    return main.addChildren(db, treeUsers, parentId).then(function(children) {
      treeUsers = Object.assign(treeUsers, children);
      --depth;
      if(depth < 1) {
        return Promise.resolve(treeUsers);
      }

      return Promise.all(Object.keys(children).map(function(id) { 
          return getChildren(id); 
      }));

  };

  return getChildren(rootNodeId);
});
```

The desired output would like this:

```
{
  '2': { id: 2, name: 'Jan'  , parent_id: 2 },
  '3': { id: 3, name: 'Mat'  , parent_id: 2 },
  '4': { id: 4, name: 'Irene', parent_id: 2 },
  '5': { id: 5, name: 'Ellie', parent_id: 2 },
  '6': { id: 6, name: 'Laura', parent_id: 5 },
  '7': { id: 7, name: 'Uma'  , parent_id: 6 }
}
```

Right now I'm getting an more like this:

```
[[     {
  '2': { id: 2, name: 'Jan'  , parent_id: 2 },
  '3': { id: 3, name: 'Mat'  , parent_id: 2 },
  '4': { id: 4, name: 'Irene', parent_id: 2 },
  '5': { id: 5, name: 'Ellie', parent_id: 2 },
  '6': { id: 6, name: 'Laura', parent_id: 5 },
  '7': { id: 7, name: 'Uma'  , parent_id: 6 }
} ],
[     {
  '2': { id: 2, name: 'Jan'  , parent_id: 2 },
  '3': { id: 3, name: 'Mat'  , parent_id: 2 },
  '4': { id: 4, name: 'Irene', parent_id: 2 },
  '5': { id: 5, name: 'Ellie', parent_id: 2 },
  '6': { id: 6, name: 'Laura', parent_id: 5 },
  '7': { id: 7, name: 'Uma'  , parent_id: 6 }
} ],
[     {
  '2': { id: 2, name: 'Jan'  , parent_id: 2 },
  '3': { id: 3, name: 'Mat'  , parent_id: 2 },
  '4': { id: 4, name: 'Irene', parent_id: 2 },
  '5': { id: 5, name: 'Ellie', parent_id: 2 },
  '6': { id: 6, name: 'Laura', parent_id: 5 },
  '7': { id: 7, name: 'Uma'  , parent_id: 6 }
} ] ... ]
```

I'm positive that the problem is the `Promise.all(getChildren(..))` call, but I'm not sure how to refactor so that I get back exactly the one final result set.

Comment: Unrelated, but why are you doing a tree traversal if you want to read a flat database structure into a flat js object structure?

Comment: If `addChildren()` adds, then surely you don't also need `treeUsers = Object.assign(treeUsers, children);`?

Comment: Also it seems wrong that `depth` should be decremented at each call of `getChildren()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some issues:

- You mutate the `treeUsers` object in both methods, which means that the object you resolve with, will still be mutated later. Note how you only have *one* instance of that object for one call of `getTreeUsers`. Note that the assignment in:

  ```
  treeUsers = Object.assign(treeUsers, children);
  ```

  does not do anything, as `Object.assign` already mutates the first argument anyway.
- `Promise.all` resolves to an array value, where each element contains the `treeUsers` object. As it was mutated by all separate calls, all these array entries point to the same object reference, explaining the repetitions you see
- `depth` is a variable common to each call to `getChildren`. It would be safer to pass it as argument to be sure that siblings are expanded with the same value for `depth`

I would just avoid passing the `treeUsers` object around, as it should really be just the resolved value. Let each promise resolve to the children it can "see" and consolidate the results after each `Promise.all` promise resolves.

Here is how that could look:

```
addChildren: function(db, treeUsers, parentId) {
    const main = this,
        sql = Sql.select().from('users')
            .where('parent_id = ?', parentId)
            .toParam();
    return db.execute(sql.text, sql.values).then(function([rs,meta]) {
        // Create a new(!) object and return it
        return Object.assign(...rs.map(function(obj) { 
            return { [obj.id]: obj };
        }));
    });
},

getTreeUsers: function(db, depth) {
    const main = this,
        rootNodeId = 1;

    const getChildren = function(parentId, depth) { // pass depth
        return main.addChildren(db, parentId).then(function(children) {
            if (depth <= 1) {
                return children; // only the children. No need for Promise.resolve
            }
            return Promise.all(Object.keys(children).map(function(id) { 
                return getChildren(id, depth - 1); // pass depth 
            })).then(arr => Object.assign(children, ...arr)); // consolidate 
        });
    }
    return getChildren(rootNodeId, depth);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `Promise.all` always returns an array of all the result values. When your calls all return promises that fulfill with the same value, `treeUsers`, you get an array of those objects. As you always want to make `getChildren` return always just that object, you can simplify to

```
function getChildren(parentId) {
  return main.addChildren(db, treeUsers, parentId).then(function(children) {
    Object.assign(treeUsers, children);

    // when `children` is empty, the recursion terminates here
    return Promise.all(Object.keys(children).map(getChildren)).then(() =>
      treeUsers
    );
  });
}
```

(Of course this does not produce a tree structure)

Comment: I like the simplicity of your answer but it doesn't appear to handle the tree depth. It should end after going 5 nodes deep in the tree.

Comment: @NoahGoodrich It ends when the queried elements have no more children. But really it's unclear what you want to do anyway, so this answer just fixes the particular issue that you asked about and nothing else.